# CSS changes don't show on xampp but show when uploaded to domain

Tags: xampp

I have a weird issue - when I try to update style changes on my localhost xampp, nothing changes.

However, when I actually upload the site to my domain, the styling changes are applied!

What do you think might be the reason for this?

Comment: Localhost cache?

Comment: How do you delete the cache?